# Deploy Tab Missing in Database Project vs2010

Tags: database-project

I am trying to change the connection settings on my database project to i can deploy the parts to a different server.

Everywhere i read it is telling me to go into the project properties and then the deploy tab, the problem is when i go into the project properties there isnt a deploy tab.

tabs are - Project Settings, SQL CLR, SQL CLR Build, Build, SQL CMD Variables, Build Events, Debug, Reference Paths, Code Analysis.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the Deploy option was left out of the menus but you can add it to a toolbar. The steps to do that are listed at the beginning of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10215374/65775).

Alternatively you can use the Publish command. The process is slightly different but the result is the same.